# XSLT Grouping & Removing Duplicate

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML where I need to Ignore the duplicates. In my given example if FaciltyId is duplicate then I have ignore all the matching records. The output should be generated for only STORE-2 and STORE-3. I have the following example but it's taking last occurrence of the duplicate node which I don't want. Could someone please guide me on that? Thank you.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:key name="x" match="FacilityId" use="."/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Item">
      <xsl:for-each select=".">
         <xsl:if test="generate-id(FacilityId) = generate-id(key('x', FacilityId)[1])">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Items>
        <MessageHeader>
           <Version>1.0</Version>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Item>
            <FacilityId>STORE-1</FacilityId>
            <ItemId>1001</ItemId>
            <ItemsType>FS</ItemsType>
            <InventoryDateTime>2016-07-05T07:00:05-07:00</InventoryDateTime>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <FacilityId>STORE-1</FacilityId>
            <ItemId>1002</ItemId>
            <ItemsType>FS</ItemsType>
            <InventoryDateTime>2016-07-05T07:00:05-07:00</InventoryDateTime>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <FacilityId>STORE-2</FacilityId>
            <ItemId>1003</ItemId>
            <ItemsType>FS</ItemsType>
            <InventoryDateTime>2016-07-05T07:00:05-07:00</InventoryDateTime>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <FacilityId>STORE-3</FacilityId>
            <ItemId>1004</ItemId>
            <ItemsType>FS</ItemsType>
            <InventoryDateTime>2016-07-05T07:00:05-07:00</InventoryDateTime>
        </Item>
    </Items>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT? 2.0 has better tools for this than 1.0 did. (Standard suggestion to check the XSLT FAQ website for many useful examples including some which are not at all obvious; http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl

Comment: I have to stick to 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if FaciltyId is duplicate then I have ignore all the matching records.
>   The output should be generated for only STORE-2 and STORE-3.

If I understand this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-facility" match="Item" use="FacilityId" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[count(key('item-by-facility', FacilityId)) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike it's working as per my needs. One thing I haven't included in my question is I have a Message Header block which needs to be copied over to output before it checks for duplicates. Something like I provided in input file. Could you please check updated Input file? Need to include Message Header Section in output. Thank you.

Comment: You could simply add `<xsl:apply-templates select="MessageHeader"/>` to the second template.